# How can i notify my C or C++ application program when an update or changes happens in mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql, c

How can i notify my C or C++ application program when an update or changes happens in mysql database.
Are there any special libraries serving this purpose?

Comment: Check out [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: @AmazingDreams What has that to do with the question?

Comment: @Carsten, for some reason I just assumed it was about a remote database... I see now that it isn't

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one out-of-the-box feature in MySQL to do this. But it is definitely possible. The following is not a step-by-step instruction, but rather the *route to take*.

1. [Create a UDF (user-defined function)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/5.7/en/adding-functions.html) for MySQL that does something that you can catch with your application, e.g. send a message over network. [Here is an example of an UDF that can send STOMP messages](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stomp). I'm sure you can adapt that to meet your needs.
2. Implement the corresponding "receive messages" functionality into your application. For example, if your UDF sends messages over a socket, make your application listen to that socket.
3. [Create a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) that fires on the events that you're trying to catch (e.g. certain UPDATEs). This trigger can call your UDF from step 1 to send messages to your application (which you'll receive thanks to step 2).

Comment: Very good answer. I would have push to the same solution myself. An approach a little bit more esoteric (that's why I post as a comment) would be to write a [custom storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html) whose only purpose would be to send message when data are inserted.

Comment: if i execute triggers in c++ connector will my C++ code wait until this trigger to come after an update or it just gets called whenever update happens

Comment: @valmiki I don't know what you mean. You define a trigger, which will then fire on a certain condition (like "whenever updates happen"). You don't execute the trigger directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) to access your mysql database on unix platform.

In order to nofify the changes in your mysql table, you could do either of the following
depending on your requirement.

1. Use a [database trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to execute a script or a program(You dont need an odbc driver).
2. Poll the database from your C/C++ program to check for any changes.
3. Write a monitor daemon that polls the database and signals your C/C++ program.

Comment: Why use ODBC and not MySQL's own C or C++ driver?

Comment: It provides a generic api hence your database access code can work for multiple databases.

Comment: @HAL DB API and (most of the time) triggers syntax are so specific to each vendor that, concerning that particular need, "portability" is probably of a less concern.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes, but if you write a trigger, you may not need odbc at all, but just call a script/program(depends a lot on what needs to be done on the data change).

Comment: Thanks for the information, sir is there any other method rather than polling, which directly gives interrupt to C/C++ application.

Comment: @valmiki You can use mysql trigger to execute a shell script that can in turn signal(for example `SIGUSR1`) your application.

Comment: if i execute triggers in c++ connector will my C++ code wait until this trigger to come after an update or it just gets called whenever update happens

Comment: @valmiki Database trigger is a procedural code that is automatically executed in response to certain event(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger). What do you mean by execute triggers in C++ connector? You don't execute a trigger.